# load only metadata from html5 video/audio

Tags: php, javascript, html5-video, html5-audio

At first, I'd like to ask that question. I can not load metadata without any other video content. `preload = "metadata"` is not working. I test on Win Chrome and don't know how it works on Safari/FF/IE/Opera. Thus I can't load six and more video clips fast. Chrome may keep *only six opened connections* at similar port/protocol/domain. And if I load more than six videos then last videos does not start load while first six videos **fully complete** loading.

Does jsfiddle need? I can create but I think that is not necessary. For example. HTML: 10 html5 `<video>` each around 100mb and `preload=metadata` attribute. JS (using jQuery just for clearness):

```
$('video').on('loadedmetadata',function(){
  console.log(this.duration);
}).each(function(i){
  this.load();
});
```

Then open “Network” tab in Chrome Dev Tools and reload page. Six videos would start to load and would load full content while other four videos would wait with `(pending)` mark. At first, in console would appear 6 messages. New messages would appear after fully load any first videos.

I tried a lot of things but each one has fall. Now I thing about getting metadata on server side. Are there any solutions on PHP maybe? But JS solution would be better.

I also know about solution which using Youtube, probably Vimeo and some other websites. That is keeping videos on some subdomains (s1.youtube.com, s2.youtube.com, etc). But I can not use it. I make website template and it have some requirements.

I have video gallery with a lot of videos. Player must show duration and know width/height before first video play. Also I want to take frame from middle of video for video poster. Any solution for stop video loading and close connection is best I need. And it solve trouble with getting metadata indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load more than 6 videos in chrome, you need to use the `.webm` format.

**Note:** If you have a bunch of sources in your video tag, like so:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
    <source src="vid.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I think chrome will default to `mp4` and not `webm`. You'll have to do some jquery magic to get it working. [Advice on that can be seen here.](http://ldki.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/20-html5-video-and-chromes-one-video.html)

Comment: why would that be the case?

Answer (score 0):

The situation is now going to be worse with v42 (currently beta - so hopefully will be fixed)

It now respects `preload='metadata'` but doesn't release the connections back to the pool so after 6 videos load it just gets completely stuck!

See bug report : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468930

Comment: v42 which was just released has this issue 'in the wild' now. It has been fixed for hopefully v43 as verified in Google Canary

Comment: Looks like the bug is still open today. It's 4 years old and refuses to die. preload="metadata" stalls on 7th network request.