# Chromium problems with MP4 and PNG only when HTML runs on PHP server

Tags: php, html, chromium

My page `index.html` is working completely fine if I open it directly with Chromium. **MP4** videos load properly

[image]

and **PNG** images (ticks) which are set as a background for checkboxes display nicely.

[image]

Because this isn't ran on a PHP server it is normal that when I click a form submit button, my PHP script downloads instead of being ran.

So I now start my PHP portable server which I have localy installed on my PC like this:

```
php -S localhost:1337 -t ~/Dropbox/internet/linux_krozki/
```

And now I use Chromium to open my page on PHP server by inputing the link:

```
http://localhost:1337/index.html
```

In general my page is now taking too long to load and all of a suden **MP4** videos won't open and neither will **PNG** images. When I press submit form, Chromium just starts to refresh and it never stops nor does it finish...

I am on Arch Linux and if I check my version with `uname -a` I get:

```
Linux ziga-laptop 4.11.9-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 5 18:23:08 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My Chromium version can be checked with `pacman -Qi chromium` which returns:

```
Name            : chromium
Version         : 60.0.3112.90-1
Description     : A web browser built for speed, simplicity, and security
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://www.chromium.org/Home
Licenses        : BSD
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : gtk3  nss  alsa-lib  xdg-utils  libxss  libcups  libgcrypt  ttf-font  systemd  dbus  libpulse  pciutils  json-glib
                  desktop-file-utils  hicolor-icon-theme  flac  opus  minizip  libpng  harfbuzz-icu  libxslt  re2  libwebp  libjpeg
                  snappy
Optional Deps   : pepper-flash: support for Flash content [installed]
                  kdialog: needed for file dialogs in KDE
                  gnome-keyring: for storing passwords in GNOME keyring
                  kwallet: for storing passwords in KWallet [installed]
Required By     : None
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 207.40 MiB                                                                                                            
Packager        : Evangelos Foutras <evangelos@foutrelis.com>                                                                           
Build Date      : Thu 03 Aug 2017 06:28:09 AM CEST                                                                                      
Install Date    : Mon 07 Aug 2017 01:15:39 AM CEST                                                                                      
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed                                                                                                  
Install Script  : Yes                                                                                                                   
Validated By    : Signature
```

No error is printed in terminal window in which I started the PHP. This is all I get after 1st opening the page, 2nd try to open a video and 3rd try to fill out the form and send it:

```
[ziga@ziga-laptop ~]$ php -S localhost:1337 -t ~/Dropbox/internet/linux_krozki/
PHP 7.1.8 Development Server started at Mon Aug  7 02:35:01 2017
Listening on http://localhost:1337
Document root is /home/ziga/Dropbox/internet/linux_krozki
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44228 [200]: /index.html
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44230 [200]: /js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44232 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=default
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44234 [200]: /css/style.css
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44236 [200]: /css/modal.css
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44238 [200]: /slike/logotip/logotip.png
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44240 [200]: /slike/linux-c-arm/prikazna/003-prikazna-small.jpg
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44242 [200]: /slike/linux-eda-cad/prikazna/003-prikazna-small.jpg
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44244 [200]: /slike/linux-blender/prikazna/003-prikazna-small.jpg
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44246 [200]: /slike/linux-photo/prikazna/003-prikazna-small.jpg
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44248 [200]: /slike/linux-audio/prikazna/003-prikazna-small.jpg
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44250 [200]: /slike/linux-latex/prikazna/003-prikazna-small.jpg
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44252 [200]: /slike/linux-desktop/prikazna/003-prikazna-small.jpg
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44254 [200]: /slike/linux-office/prikazna/003-prikazna-small.jpg
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44256 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/config/default.js?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44258 [200]: /slike/wallpaper/005.gif
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44260 [200]: /fonts/alegreya-sans-b1.ttf
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44262 [200]: /fonts/alegreya-sans-b3.ttf
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44264 [200]: /fonts/fontawesome.ttf                                                                      
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44266 [200]: /fonts/alegreya-sans-b2.ttf                                                                 
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44268 [200]: /fonts/garamond.ttf                                                                         
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44270 [200]: /slike/kontaktni-obrazec/001.gif                                                            
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44272 [200]: /slike/prijavni-obrazec/006.jpg                                                             
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44274 [200]: /slike/prijavni-obrazec/selectbox-button.png                                                
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44276 [200]: /video/test.mp4                                                                             
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44278 [200]: /video/test.mp4                                                                             
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44280 [200]: /video/test.mp4                                                                             
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44282 [200]: /video/test.mp4                                                                             
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44284 [200]: /video/test.mp4                                                                             
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:11 2017] ::1:44286 [200]: /video/test.mp4                                                                             
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44288 [200]: /video/test.mp4                                                                             
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44290 [200]: /video/test.mp4                                                                             
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44292 [200]: /video/test.mp4
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44294 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/jax/input/TeX/config.js?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44296 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/jax/output/HTML-CSS/config.js?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44298 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/extensions/tex2jax.js?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44300 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/jax/element/mml/jax.js?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44302 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/jax/input/TeX/jax.js?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44304 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/jax/output/HTML-CSS/jax.js?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44306 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/TeX/fontdata.js?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44308 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/extensions/MathEvents.js?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44310 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Main-Regular.woff?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44312 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Math-Italic.woff?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:12 2017] ::1:44314 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Size1-Regular.woff?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:13 2017] ::1:44316 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/extensions/TeX/AMSmath.js?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:13 2017] ::1:44320 [200]: /js/mathjax-2.7.1/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff/MathJax_Size2-Regular.woff?V=2.7.1
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:13 2017] ::1:44322 [200]: /video/test.mp4
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:13 2017] ::1:44324 [200]: /video/test.mp4
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:13 2017] ::1:44326 [200]: /video/test.mp4
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:14 2017] ::1:44328 [200]: /video/test.mp4
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:14 2017] ::1:44330 [200]: /video/test.mp4
[Mon Aug  7 02:35:14 2017] ::1:44332 [200]: /video/test.mp4
```

I don't really know what to do. If I open my page that runs on PHP server with Firefox 54.0.1-1 everything works completely fine. With Opera 46.0 I can't play MP4 videos as there are no propietary drivers installed so this is supposed to be normal, while everything else works. If I open the page with Qupzilla 2.1.2, which is a derivative from Chromium MP4 videos work fine, but PNG images don't and I can't submit the form.

I really don't know how to continue... I need suggestions...

---

As sugested I am adding screenshot of Chromium's network window as soon after page loads and I press the checkbox. It looks like `test.mp4` videos are preloaded except for one which is `pending` forever. When I click on a checkbox image `selectbox-kljukica.png` also tries to load but it is `pending` forever too.

[image]

When in am Chromium network view and I click on the `pending` item `selectbox-kljukica.png` I get this info:

[image]

When I click on `pending` item `test.mp4` I get this instead:

[image]

---

I figured one more symptom. If I make haste and click the checkbox before MP$ videos start to load, `selectbox-kljukica.png` gets loaded and then works withouth any problem, so the real problem must lie in MP4...

Comment: Can you check the network log in chromium `ctrl`+`alt`+`J` > Network and check if the video is even loading correctly?

Comment: What are you getting for the `Content-Type` headers?

Comment: @Brad If I open `/etc/php/php.ini` file and search for `content-type` i get this line `default_mimetype = "text/html"`. I tried to make it empty like this `default_mimetype = ` and something weird happened. Chromium started working flawlesly untill it stopped again for no reason. Now Content-type header is stil empty but symptoms persist. How come it worked in between?

Comment: @lumio I added the network window from Chromium. I hope it helps.

Comment: either you filtered the network window just for scripts or your video is not loading. The error might occur because you try to pause a video but there is no video to pause

Comment: @lumio I set video to `preload="auto" and nothing changed... So my video isn't loading on PHP server for some reason while it loads withouth any problem if html file doesn't run on PHP server.

Comment: Can you show us the full network output? Or at least filter for the video locally and on the server

Comment: @lumio OK. I gota bit more  familiar with network output which I added to the question. So I disabled the cache and recorded the webpage after emptying the cache and hard reload. Just for the record I have no Chromium extensions installed.

Comment: After some research I found out that other people also have problems using Google Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443105/load-only-metadata-from-html5-video-audio What I experienced here was actually a Google Chrome bug! Google chrome fails to load more than 6 MP4 videos. 7th video is always `pending` and after this happens nothing works. PNG images wont load anymore, my PHP scripts won't execute and input data into my database... So I prevented videos from loading using `preload="none"` parameter and my page now works... Untill user clicks his 7th video... What a shame...